# When using the getInstance() method of the abstract java.text.NumberFormat class, what is the actual class of the return value?

Tags: java, text, abstract, number-formatting

This question expands upon the one at [abstract-class-numberformat-very-confused-about-getinstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438508/abstract-class-numberformat-very-confused-about-getinstance). I feel that this question is different enough to merit being asked on its own.

In the answers to that question, it was stated that a code statement such as

```
NumberFormat en = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
```

returns an object that is a subclass of the `java.text.NumberFormat` class. It makes sense to me why the return type can't be *just* an instance of `NumberFormat` since that is an abstract class. Rather, it was stated that the returned object is *at least* an instance of `NumberFormat`, but actually something else.

My question is this: what specifically is the class of the object that is returned? In the Sun documentation the only subclasses I see are `ChoicesFormat` and `DecimalFormat`. Is there some sort of behind the scenes compiler voodoo going on here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No compiler voodoo at all, just plain old polymorphism. :-)

Comment: You could call `System.out.println(en.getClass().getName())` to see what it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific type is not specified, because it can be any subclass of `NumberFormat`. It might even depend on the locale you use. Some locales may require a `ChoiceFormat` to implement correctly, for others `DecimalFormat` is sufficient and for a third locale they might even return a locale-specific implementation.

The fact that it's not defined more specifically than the abstract base class allows this kind of change in the implementation without having to change the method signature to accommodate such a change.

You can easily verify which concrete type is returned by *one specific call* by calling `getClass()` on the returned value.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of factory pattern.

The API designers didn't want to require the caller to know the concrete subtype of NumberFormat. If the caller "cares" what concrete classes may be returned Evil Things like the instanceof operator start appearing. When stuff like that happens, all the sudden the caller is "tightly coupled" to the concrete subclass and not just the "interface" (where interface can mean a Java interface, abstract class or even some other non-final class).

Most OO advocates want you to shoot for "high encapsulation, loose coupling".

Answer (score 0):

Why not run...

```
System.out.println(NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US).getClass().getName());
```

... and find out?

Comment: good question. I'm embarrassed to say that the idea didn't even occur to me. point taken :)

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org) console in [Jedit](http://jedit.org), I get the following:

```
BeanShell> import java.text.NumberFormat;
BeanShell> NumberFormat en = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
BeanShell> en.getClass().getName();
java.text.DecimalFormat
```

I would say that DecimalFormat is returned by that call.